# Magento Cloud reindex fail elasticsuite

Tags: product, catalog, reindex

I try to reindex my Magento Cloud and caught below error. Anyone whats wrong with the ElasticSuite

```
web@mymagento.0:~$ php bin/magento indexer:reindex
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:04
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product/Target Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Target Rule/Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:05
Google Product Removal Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Google Product Feed index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Sales Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exce     ptions\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable      $previous = NULL]]]) in /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearc     h/Connections/Connection.php:682
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connect     ion.php(682): Exception->__construct(NULL, 503)
#1 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connect     ion.php(298): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array     , Array)
#2 /app/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connect     ions\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React     \Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\Comp     letedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#5 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src in /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elas     ticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 682

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Wrong parameters for Elasticsearch\Common\Exception     s\ServerErrorResponseException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $prev     ious = NULL]]]) in /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Con     nections/Connection.php:682
Stack trace:
#0 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connect     ion.php(682): Exception->__construct(NULL, 503)
#1 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connect     ion.php(298): Elasticsearch\Connections\Connection->process5xxError(Array, Array     , Array)
#2 /app/vendor/react/promise/src/FulfilledPromise.php(25): Elasticsearch\Connect     ions\Connection->Elasticsearch\Connections\{closure}(Array)
#3 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Future/CompletedFutureValue.php(55): React     \Promise\FulfilledPromise->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#4 /app/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Core.php(341): GuzzleHttp\Ring\Future\Comp     letedFutureValue->then(Object(Closure), NULL, NULL)
#5 /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src in /app/vendor/elasticsearch/elas     ticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php on line 682
web@mymagento.0:~$
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue and it turned out that it was beacause the search engine we used was `Elasticsearch`. We changed it in `Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search` to `Elasticsearch 6.0+` and we solved.

Hope this could be helpful for you as well

Answer (score 0):

From the Magento support, they said due to the huge amount of stored data. so They clear them out for me. The command they use to clear the data is

```
 curl -sS elasticsearch.internal:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
 cat .magento.app.yaml
 curl -sS elasticsearch.internal:9200/_cluster/health?pretty
 curl -sS  "elasticsearch.internal:9200/_cat/nodes?h=heap*&v"
 curl elasticsearch.internal:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to you are using elasticsuite but in configuration elasticsearch is assigned, So please assign elasticsuite and their dependent plugins in `.magento.app.yaml` and mention servers for the same in `.magento.env.yaml` file.

File looks like:-

**.magento.app.yaml**

```
    runtime:
    extensions:
        - xsl
        - newrelic
        - sodium

relationships:
    database: "mysql:mysql"
    redis: "redis:redis"
    opensearch: "opensearch:opensearch"
```

**.magento.env.yaml**

```
stage:
  deploy:
    ELASTICSUITE_CONFIGURATION:
      es_client:
        servers: '127.0.0.1:9200,opensearch.internal:9200'
```

After adding these in yaml file push these files then the indexer will work with elasticsuit.